# Autocomplete feature on Android using SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, autocomplete

I am trying to develop a simple dictionary. Dictionary contains around a hundred thousand entries. I want to show autocomplete in a list as user types in the textbox. I tried LIKE operator in SQLite but it is too slow. I heard something like Full Text Search. However I am not sure if it is appropriate for my needs.

To visualize what I want to achieve, here is a screenshot of an Android dictionary [Advanced English & Thesaurus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisystems.msdict.embedded.wireless.wordnet):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible; you want to use an [`AutoCompleteTextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html). There are several good tutorials on how to use it, if you do a search.